# Copying/merging a folder in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Apologies for the poor title as I'm struggling to explain this.

I have a folder (called Content) and a batch file in a directory. I'm trying to write a .bat file that copies the Content folder in it's entirety, not just the contents to another directory on the system.

So the source folder contains:

```
Content (folder)
run.bat
(there may be extra files in here too)
```

The destination folder also contains a folder called Content. I'm trying to copy the Content folder from the source folder into the destination folder.

The closest I've managed to set to achieving this is with robocopy using this command:

`ROBOCOPY "." "%DIRECTORY%" /E /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /nfl`

However this copies every other file in the source directory. I only want to copy the Content folder, how would I achieve this?

From what I've read, you can only tell robocopy to exclude items rather than include them. Because the source folders may contain a lot of different files. I don't want it to copy those to the destination as they're not required.

Comment: What about this: `robocopy "Content" "%DIRECTORY%\Content" /E /NJH /NJS /NDL /NC /NS /NFL`? Note that `.` is the *current working directory* but **not** necessarily the parent directory of your batch file!

Comment: Doesn't work. The %DIRECTORY% variable somehow has a space on the end so it's being treated as a new folder entirely. So I might need to see if I can trim the whitespace off the variable.

Comment: Jake, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57559723/edit) to provide us with enough of your code for us to replicate your issue. Firstly you told us that you want to copy a directory named `Content`, but then provided code showing a variable named `%DIRECTORY%`, we need to see the code which defines this variable, especially because you've informed us that it has an unwanted trailing space. You've also shown a file named `run.bat` adjacent to the source directory, is that file supposed to be the running script you need assistance with? or an unrelated batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the file, as this solution would be rather annoying for large files, you can use something like this:

```
%save%< %directory%/content/%filename% (
set /p line1=
set /p line2=
set /p line3=
rem etc
)
(
echo %line1%
echo %line2%
echo %line3%
rem etc
) > %newdirectory%/content/%filename%
```